# Java Batch Insert into MySQL very slow

Tags: java, mysql, performance, batch-file, insert

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JDBC batch insert performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993251/jdbc-batch-insert-performance)

I have the following method in a class:

```
    public void insertShingleSets(Vector<ShingleSet> shingleSets)
    {
        String sql = "INSERT   INTO tblPostingsShingles("+
                "rowId, " +                    
                "shingle) " +                     
                "VALUES(?,?);";

        PreparedStatement statement = null;
        try {
            statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            for (int i = 0; i < shingleSets.size(); i++)
            {   String id = shingleSets.get(i).getRowId();
                String shingle = shingleSets.get(i).getShingle();
                statement.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(id));
                statement.setString(2, shingle);
                statement.addBatch();
                if ((i + 1) % 1000 == 0) {
                    System.out.println("doing a batch " + i);         //-------------
                    statement.executeBatch(); // Execute every 1000 items.
                    System.out.println("done batch " + i);            //-------------
                             }
            }
            statement.executeBatch();
        }
       catch (SQLException ex)
            {
                // handle any errors
                System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
                System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
                System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
            }

        finally {
            if (statement != null)
                try { statement.close();
                } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
            if (conn != null)
                try { conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
        }
    }
```

The time between executing: System.out.println("doing a batch " + i);
and executing: System.out.println("done batch " + i); 
is about 30 seconds which seems rather a lot considering it's only inserting two columns into a three column table (the other column is an autonumber primary key and when starting/testing there were no rows in the table).
The only thing I can think of is that before this method is called, another method uses a query that checks in the table tblPostingsShingles to check if certain rowIds are there. However, I would have thought that any locks would be released when that method finishes (it has the same finally clause as this method).
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
Dave

Comment: Just a thought if you close the connection in every method, who is reopening it?

Answer (score 1):

You can experiment with batch sizes, but I've had processes that seemed quite fast at 500 a batch and 1000 is not overly large - there's no obvious reason that I can see that that would take so long - it's easily an order of magnitude too slow.

Other possible performance bottlenecks are your mysql configuration and network connection speed. Is this speed any faster than doing a single write at a time?

Comment: I'm a bit new to mysql. However it's installed on the same computer (i.e. localserver). I would have thought that something would appear in the mysql.slow_log but it's empty. I haven't knowingly altered any of the configurations but is there a way I can check these? It just seems ridiculously slow. I presume network connection would not be applicable here due to localserver?? I timed how long it took to insert one row and calculated it as 70702840 nanoseconds which is 0.07 of a second. Isn't that quite a bit? Thanks for any advice

Comment: On your local box that seems very slow, unless your local box is a circa-1990 ibm pc-junior. I don't think the slow-log will show inserts, though I wouldn't swear to it. Also try turning off autocommit in the driver before batch processing and manually triggering the commit after.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest experimenting with a smaller batch size.  Generally, when I do batch inserts I limit the size to 20 - 50 rows at a time.  Right now with 1000 row batch, your job is likely blocking on database and network I/O.  If you cut down the batch size you may be able to speed up the process.

Comment: Making batch smaller can improve time of processing a batch but how it will effect overall processing time?

Comment: sure, I reduced it from 1000 to 200 but it takes longer than a fifth of the time - i.e. still takes about 8-10 seconds to do 200 rows

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty bad. I found this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-speed.html, you might want to check out the part about LOCK TABLES, would you be able to test with that?

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I think it was my computer or something - using another one and it seems ok.