# How to update sparse values in a database table?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, relational-database

What is the best practice to update a table record most effectively (in my case with a primary key), when not all values are present?

Imagine:

```
PRIMARY_KEY1, COLUMN_2, COLUMN_3, COLUMN_4, COLUMN_5, COLUMN_6, ...
```

I always get tuples like `(PRIMARY_KEY1, COLUMN_5, COLUMN_4)` or `(PRIMARY_KEY1, COLUMN_2, COLUMN_6, COLUMN_3)` and want to just update them in the fastest way possible without having a database lookup for all other values.

Since I have to to this very fast, I would like to use something like batches for prepared statements in order to prevent massive database requests.

Thanks for all replies!

Comment: are you talking about ad hoc updates in some SQL editor or from within an application?

Comment: "prevent massive database requests." - how massive? a modern RDBMS can handle many transactions....

Comment: I forgot to add the java/jdbc tag, so I want to do this in java. 
I want to process around 50k requests per second of that kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can 'cheat' by expecting SQL to fill in the values at row-access time.  Eg, this type of statement:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET (column_1, column_2, ..., column_6)
                      = (COLAESCE(@suppliedValue1, column_1),
                         COLAESCE(@suppliedValue2, column_2),
                         ...,
                         COLAESCE(@suppliedValue6, column_6))
WHERE primary_Key1 = @primaryKey
```

Then, when filling out the parameters, just leave anything unsupplied `null`... and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

you are not required to update the entire row in SQL.  just use UPDATEs SET syntax.

```
UPDATE table SET COLUMN_5 = 'foo', COLUMN_4 = 'goo' WHERE PRIMARY_KEY1 = 'hoo';
```

Comment: but for that I have to to a single request for each tuple, imagine I want to process around 50,000 per second.

Answer (score 0):

See this post here,

[JDBC batch insert performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993251/jdbc-batch-insert-performance?rq=1)

Read it. Then look on the right column of the page under related links for other similar posts
You should find all the answers you need in no time.