# JDBC prepared statement, batch insert performance improvement

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement, batch-insert

I have a huge set of data, and i want to insert them on database at once, i used prepared statement with batch insert but it takes around `15 seconds` on `pstmt.executeBatch()`.
I'm looking for best results (around `5 seconds`), how could i achieve my goal?

auto commit is disabled.

number of insert statements: 100000 statement.

Comment: What's your batch size?

Comment: What is your database? If MySQL, see  http://stackoverflow.com/q/2993251/25122