# Storing large chunk of data in spring jdbc template

Tags: java, oracle, rest, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

i have an oracle query which would result in thousands of rows (around 70k). i am using spring jdbc template and rowmapper to execute the query and storing all the records in the rowmapper , but this operation takes around 5-10 mins , which is not preferrable as API standpoint , i want to reduce this time , is there any other method/approach by which i can store this large chunk of data from oracle into my java. please advice.

Please Note: i have a select query , and no insertions/update operations , so i can't go with batch Update.

Answer (score 0):

you can refer these link for batch insert/update in Spring : -

https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-jdbctemplate-batchupdate-example/

and

[why spring jdbcTemplate batchUpdate insert row by row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576061/why-spring-jdbctemplate-batchupdate-insert-row-by-row)

Comment: Actually , i have a select query which would give me large chunk of data , and i need them in java somewhere as i need to do some other filtration on that data . since there is no insertion/deletion involved , i don't think batchUpdate will work in my case.