# How to include two parameters for jdbctemplate.batchUpdate(String sql, List<Object[]> batchArgs)?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, jdbctemplate

I am trying to perform an UPDATE on a MySQL database where I update only one single column full of values corresponding to the correct index position. Here is my current code:

```java
JdbcTemplate temp = new JdbcTemplate(sqlDataSource);
List<Map<String, Object>> results = temp.queryForList("SELECT last_name FROM actor");
List<Object[]> params = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

for (Map<String, Object> row : results) {
    params.add(new Object[]{row.get("last_name"), row.get("actor_id")});
}

String sql = "UPDATE actor SET first_name= ? WHERE actor_id=?";

temp.batchUpdate(sql, params)
```

In this example, I am trying to update all first names in my table to the last names. My main question is how can I include a parameter for the "SET first_name = ?" as well as the WHERE condition "WHERE actor_id = ?" as well? Is this possible with JdbcTemplate?

Answer (score -1):

I think a simple Google search can solve your problem(s).
If you just look up JdbcTemplate batchUpdate, it should guide you in the right direction.
With that said, have a look at these:

- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/springjdbc/springjdbc_jdbctemplate
- [why spring jdbcTemplate batchUpdate insert row by row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576061/why-spring-jdbctemplate-batchupdate-insert-row-by-row)

Comment: Google searches can get outdated. Answer the question. If you can't be bothered to, don't bother providing just links.