Why JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate() from spring-core 5.3.31 is comparitevely very slower than spring-core 4.2.9.RELEASE
I am using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate class in Spring Boot application.
and my app has a bulk upload feature. I am updating specific columns but currently observing ->
with spring-core 4.2.9.RELEASE: This takes around 4 seconds

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

and with spring-core-5.3.31 the same takes 3 minutes.
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.31</version>
</dependency>

Database Dependency
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
    <version>19.3.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ucp</artifactId>
    <version>19.19.0.0</version>
</dependency>

After verifying my code, I found that
jdbctemplate.batchUpdate() is taking longer in the newer version.
// lets say BATCH_SIZE is 100
final List<Map<String,?>> batchedRecords = new ArrayList<>(BATCH_SIZE);

@Autowired
private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

Below is the main method. which is taking the data form the JSON payload. Some data processing is happening, and then after processing that record is inserted into batchedRecords.
Map<String, Object> record;
for(Iterator<JsonNode> saveRecs= dataNode.elements(); saveRecs.hasNext();) {
    record = new HashMap<>();
    // some processing
    insert( record);
}
done();


public final void insert(final Map<String, ?> record) {
    batchedRecords.add(record);
    recordCount++;
    if (batchedRecords.size() == BATCH_SIZE) {
        runBatrchInsert();
    }
}

private void runBatchInsert() {
    Map<String, ?>[] recordArr = new HashMap[batchedRecords.size()];
    // here I have set recordArr elements from batchedRecords data.
    jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql, recordArr);
}

private void done(){
    runBatchInsert();
}

FYI -> I am using JDBC:thin URL in application.properties for setting up connection with the db.
application.properties
jdbc.ora.url: jdbcLoracle:thin:@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
jdbc.ora.user:
jdbc.ora.password:

Below are my Beans
@Autowired
private HikariOracleDataSourceFactory ds;

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource(){
    return ds.createDataSource("ora");
}

@Bean
public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource datasource){
    return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(datasource);
}

I have tried many solutions available online, but none of them is working for me
could someone please explain what changed here?

Have you compared the SQL queries that are being executed in each case? That may help to narrow down the source of the problem.

@AndyWilkinson SQL query remains the same.
My application was working fine until I decided to upgrade the dependencies.
and This spring-core version upgrade is causing this issue.

In that case, I would try profiling the app to see where the huge amount of additional time is being spent. Is it somewhere in the app, or is the DB, for some as yet unknown reason, taking longer to process each query.

I already mentioned that in my question.
jdbcTemplate.bactchUpdate() is taking longer in the newer version. I have already analyzed that.

"jdbctemplate.batchUpdate() is taking longer in the newer version" doesn't provide the information that I asked for. There's quite a lot that happens within batchUpdate, including the remote calls to the DB. We don't know if the time is being spent on the client side within Spring Framework's code or the JDBC driver, on network IO between the JVM and the DB, or in the DB itself. Profiling the application and sharing the data will help to figure that out.

Unfortunately, I cannot share my actual code for now.
Could you at least help update us on why this is happening?
What changes are made with the batchUpdate() method in the newer version?
I tried following this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20360574/why-springs-jdbctemplate-batchupdate-so-slow
but it didn't helped

I don't know why it's happening. That's why I'm asking for more data.

No problem. Thanks for your time.
