# Why are MySQL PreparedStatements not automatically closed in Java upon GC?

Tags: java, mysql, garbage-collection

In my early Java web applications, I would `close` the `Connection` at the end of each request. I would not close `ResultSet` or `PreapredStatement` because they are closed automatically when the `Connection` is closed.

However, some of my applications had to create many `PreparedStatement`s in a loop. So that if I did not `close` them individually, I would get an `OutOfMemory` error before the request could finish. It seems that each `Connection` keeps references to all of its `PreparedStatement`s.

I'm used to Perl automatically cleaning up the statement (`$sth`) when the variable becomes inaccessible (i.e. subroutine returns). If `$sth` is still accessible when I call `$dbh->disconnect`, then I have to call `$sth->finish`, but most times it is not accessible at the end of my scripts and that is not necessary.

I would think that Java could give the developer similar convenience using the `finalize` method and possibly using `WeakReference`. The `finalize` method is called when all references are gone and the object is inaccessible. (except using weak references)

1. Would this be a reasonable solution to automatically closing `PreparedStatement`s? If so, I am planning to create wrapper functions to achieve such automation in my application. If that's not a reasonable solution, please explain.
2. What would be the likely side-effects that prevented the the designers of the [MySQL-Java Connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) (a JDBC driver) from including this automation in their original design?
3. The only side-effect I can think of would be memory overhead in the MySQL server itself. However, I don't know whether the MySQL server even has any overhead when a `PreparedStatement` remains open. Is there any memory kept overhead in MySQL?

Comment: relevant here:- https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=88021

Answer (score 0):

The finalize method runs when the JVM decides it needs to - it may or may not run when the object goes out of scope.  It is not the same as a C++ destructor for example.  You should not need to create PreparedStatements in a loop - the whole point is that they are "prepared" and can be used many times.  That doesn't mean it should live forever but it should be reused if, in your example, you need to loop over something.

In short - never count on finalize.  If you open something then close it.  If at all possible use the AutoClosable interface in new code so that you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: *"You should not need to create PreparedStatements in a loop"* In some situations this is the most expedient approach. Remember this question is about developer convenience in situations where optimal efficiency is not of great importance.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm used to Perl automatically cleaning up the statement

I can imagine two reasons:

- The `Connection` is probably referenced strongly with the `Driver`. This could be replaced by a `WeakReference`, but it won't do what you need (see below).
- Perl has tons of built-in special features making programming more convenient and this may be one of them: "When a variable can be freed when leaving a sub, it will be freed."

> I would think that Java could give the developer similar convenience using the `finalize` method and possibly using `WeakReference`.

No way. GC is only a tool for reclaiming memory, misusing it for anything else does not work (see below).

> 1. Would this be a reasonable solution to automatically closing `PreparedStatement`s?

No. All it's practically good for is helping you find out whether and where you're leaking resources, so you can fix it. The problem is that other resources may get exhausted much faster leaving you with tons of memory, but e.g., no single free file descriptor. The GC won't trigger because of this. You could call `System.gc` manually, but it'd waste a lot of time.

> 2. What would be the likely side-effects that prevented the the designers of the MySQL-Java Connector ... from including this automation in their original design?

It just can't work. If it was possible, then it'd be implemented in JDBC, so that the Driver authors wouldn't need to bother.

> 3. The only side-effect I can think of would be memory overhead in the MySQL server itself.

I'd bet, when the `MySQLConnection` gets closed, it tells the server to release associated resources, too. There are [such resources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32645365/581205).

---

I'd strongly recommend to forget about using GC for this. There's no perfect solution in Java, but there are many good ones:

- Since Java 7, you can use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).
- You can use [@Cleanup](https://projectlombok.org/features/Cleanup.html) from Project Lombok.
- You can write a class doing all the work including the cleanup and converting the `ResultSet` to a `List<Object[]>` if you have enough memory.
- You can use the [Template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) with an abstract method specifying how to process a result row.
- You can use one of thousands tools out there....

Comment: That is a [very interesting link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32645365/581205) about client vs server prepared statements. Also I like the idea of using a helper method and collecting all the results into a `List` object when I have enough memory.

Comment: *"The problem is that other resources may get exhausted much faster leaving you with tons of memory, but e.g., no single free file descriptor."* Hmm. I don't think we'll have a problem with file descriptors in this setup. But maybe that is just an example. I really am looking for specifics. Like I said, the only (specific) issue I can see would be memory overhead in the *server*. I still need to research whether the server overhead is influenced by timing of `PreparedStatement.close`. I'll look at [that link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32645365/581205).

Comment: Based on what I can tell, server-side overhead would only occur if `useServerPrepStmts` was enabled. This is a great feature so I think I will start to enable this in my applications moving forward. It does mean that my idea with using `finalize` would no longer be a good one. I am still interested to know if there are any specific issues if we were **not** going to enable `useServerPrepStmts`. So far I see none.