# why preparedStatement in java doesn't send a PREPARE and EXECUTE command?

Tags: java, mysql

When the code below is executed,

```java
        public static void prep(Connection conn) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("Prepare");

                PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE lower(customer_name) LIKE ?");

                stmt.setString(1, "%"+'J'+"%");


                ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery();
                showResult(rset);

                stmt.setString(1, "%"+'E'+"%");
                rset = stmt.executeQuery();
                showResult(rset);
        }
```

general log in MySQL is like this.

```
2020-07-17T07:24:21.289065Z       107 Query     SELECT * FROM customers WHERE lower(customer_name) LIKE '%J%'
2020-07-17T07:24:21.315094Z       107 Query     SELECT * FROM customers WHERE lower(customer_name) LIKE '%E%'
```

But as I know, when using preparedStatement, the log should be formed like this?

('PREPARE' Statement is sent to DBMS and 'EXECUTE' statement is followed.)

```
2020-07-17T06:03:55.083909Z        96 Prepare   SELECT * FROM customers WHERE lower(customer_name) LIKE ?
2020-07-17T06:03:55.084115Z        96 Execute   SELECT * FROM customers WHERE lower(customer_name) LIKE '%J%'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is duplicated with [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32286518/whats-the-difference-between-cacheprepstmts-and-useserverprepstmts-in-mysql-jdb)

There are two kinds of prepared statement cache.

1. client side prepared statement cache.
2. server side prepared statement cache.

My case is just first one which means that `preparedStatement` Object is cached in the client side and this can be reused when the statement string is same.

When you want to use the second one, then `useServerPrepStmts` jdbc property should be set to `true`.

Then the general log may look like this way.

```
2020-07-17T06:03:55.083909Z        96 Prepare   SELECT * FROM customers WHERE lower(customer_name) LIKE ?
2020-07-17T06:03:55.084115Z        96 Execute   SELECT * FROM customers WHERE lower(customer_name) LIKE '%J%'
```