# What happens when the number of updated rows exceeds 2^31?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jtds

I have some code that will potentially insert a huge number of rows into a table. I'm currently using Spring's `JdbcTemplate.update` to execute the SQL, but I have a concern.

The method, like bare JDBC's `Statement.executeUpdate` to which it delegates, returns an `int`, where the maximum value is of course 2<sup>31</sup> = 2147483648.

So, the question is, what does JDBC do in such a situation? Return MAX_INTEGER, some other number, throw an exception? Or perhaps the behavior is platform- (or driver-) specific? I'm supporting both SQL Server (through jTDS) and Oracle (through the thin driver).

Comment: Wait, will your application _really_ insert more than 2 billion rows in the same statement? Or is it a purely theoretical question?

Comment: Yes, in a rare circumstance; broadly speaking, it's copying (transformed) rows from one table to another.

Comment: I don't think you should use Java for this. If it's copying data from one table to another, use your DB tools (like a stored procedure). I can't even begin to realize how long serializing this data and sending to the DB back and forth will take, but I guess it will be enormous (enormous enough that there is no question anymore because the application will just die right there).

Comment: You would probably get a better performance by splitting the updates in several batches of say 1m records and probably even better by using the database batch import facility (via a csv file or similar). See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993251/jdbc-batch-insert-performance

Comment: or use an ETL tool for this, like Pentaho Kettle

Comment: FYI, in Java 8 there is a [`executeLargeUpdate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeLargeUpdate-java.lang.String-) which returns a `long` but you would have to make sure the JDBC driver supports it.

Comment: I might have given the wrong impression; data is not flowing through the Java app. When you execute an `insert` with a `select`, all the work is done in the DMBS. I appreciate the concern regarding the best approach (like a dedicated ETL tool). At this point, I'm primarily interested in the behavior under such a condition.

Answer (score 1):

In JDBC 4.2 (which is part of Java 8) we have: The `Statement` class has a method `executeLargeUpdate` for executing an update whose row count exceeds `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html

Comment: That would help... it looks like Microsoft has a JDBC 4.2 compliant driver, but I don't find one for Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

It's driver dependent, because Statement is an Interface that must be implemented by the vendor's jdbc driver.

For an example, this is what happens inside the MySQL jdbc driver

```
public int executeUpdate(String sql) throws SQLException {
    return Util.truncateAndConvertToInt(executeLargeUpdate(sql));
}
```

which means

```
public static int truncateAndConvertToInt(long longValue) {
    return longValue > Integer.MAX_VALUE ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : longValue < Integer.MIN_VALUE ? Integer.MIN_VALUE : (int) longValue;
}
```

So in this specific case, for this specific driver, it will return Integer.MAX_VALUE and no exception will be thrown.

MySQL jdbc driver and source code are available here http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/