# How programatically set rewriteBatchedStatements for mysql jdbc driver?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993251/jdbc-batch-insert-performance) is a way to speed up batch insert performance. Can `rewriteBatchedStatements` be set programatically, **not** via url?

Comment: My be this existing question in SO will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26307760/mysql-and-jdbc-with-rewritebatchedstatements-true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to do it through the URL, you can use the `Properties` object with `DriverManager`:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("user", ...);
props.setProperty("password", ...);
props.setProperty("rewriteBatchedStatements", "true");
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
```

If you use a `MysqlDataSource` or `MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource` then you need to set the property `rewriteBatchedStatements` (or call setter `setRewriteBatchedStatements(boolean)`

To change this at runtime after you have obtained a connection, you should be able to use:

```
((com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionProperties) connection).setRewriteBatchedStatements(true);
```

Note: I have only looked at the MySQL Connector/J sources for this last option, I haven't tested it.

**UPDATED**

For **c3p0** you can use the following:

```
ComboPooledDataSource cpds = ...
Connection connection = cpds.getConnection();
connection.unwrap(com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionProperties.class).setRewriteBatchedStatements(true);
```

c3p0 should be `com.mchange:c3p0:0.9.5.2`, be carefull with `com.mchange` - with other groupId this code does not work.

Comment: @Cherry Thanks for the edit. I totally forgot to mention `unwrap`, it will probably work for the normal MySQL connection, and for wrapped MySQL connections of other data sources as well.