# Low JDBC write speed from Spark to MySQL

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I need write about 1 million rows from Spark a DataFrame to MySQL but the insert is too slow. How can I improve it?

Code below:

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
df.write.jdbc(url='xx', table='xx', mode='overwrite')
```

Comment: Spark since 1.6.0 [supports batch inserts](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10040), so if you use older version - upgrade. If you can't upgrade for some reason, get RDD from your DataFrame and do batch insert by hand in foreachPartition loop.

Comment: I'm using Spark 1.6.1 but the write speed is about 100 records/s. Can Dataframe repartition helpful here?

Comment: The default batch size is 1000. Maybe increasing it would speed things up? I'm giving that a try now! (You can set it through the `batchsize` property.)

Comment: Where do you get `schema` from? @DanielDarabos

Comment: A more typical example would be to load the DataFrame directly via `spark.read` or use `RDD.toDF`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/10617768/3318517 has worked for me. Add `rewriteBatchedStatements=true` to the connection URL. (See [Configuration Properties for Connector/J](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html).)

My benchmark went from 3325 seconds to 42 seconds!