# Whats the fastest between adding row by row and multiple row in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I'm parsing a large text file to add it into mySQL database, the file is more than 10K lines, each lines with more than 20 columns (line seperated by ",").

Before I start coding, I wanted to know which is the best way (in term of memory and execution time) between those two solutions :

1. The easy way : Line by line

Adding row by row (more than 10K insert into) : The easiest way

2. Complicated way

Parsing the whole file, creating ArrayList for each column, then inserting all the data in only one statement.

Does the "complicated way" save me a lot in the execution time ?

Thanks

Comment: [How to import CSV file to MySQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635166/how-to-import-csv-file-to-mysql-table)

Comment: No. The correct way is [JDBC batching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993251/jdbc-batch-insert-performance). When you process your `ArrayList`, you would then be inserting all the data one row at a time.

Comment: you might want to insert your data in batches, say 1K at a time for your example.

Comment: `load data infile`:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

Comment: the load data infile seems interesting, thanks all !

Comment: For such a tiny data set, it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the solutions of @Gordon Linoff I was able to do it :

The request to execute in Java was :

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.txt' INTO TABLE TableName FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';';
```